# Fetch URL from page before redirecting to another URL

Tags: url, redirect, apex

I have a list view button placed on Account object. I wanted to fetch the current page url on click of that button. I have tried `{!$Currentpage.parameters.<parameterName>}`. But I am getting the URL after redirection. Is there any way to capture the URL before redirection to some other url. Please help me on this. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the above issue.

```
var vfRetURLInSFX = '{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.vfRetURLInSFX)}';
```

Using above code snippet we can fetch the page url from Lightning List View Button..